# How to add unity-greeter in Debian wheezy with GDM 3

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, ubuntu-unity

There are two questions I would like to ask.

1) How do we install unity-greeter in Debian wheezy with GDM 3 to have an Ubuntu style login screen ?

2) How do we have a rounded-styled login box with default gdm 3 setup ?